Is the universe "one-sided"?
I have asked this question on Physics Stack Exchange, but it was closed because it does not deal with mainstream physics, that is, physics for which some paper has been published. I think it is worth asking here, due to its metaphysical implications.
String theory sets out to provide a quantum theory of gravity, and hence answer the question, "Why are Einstein's field equations true?"
I have a very basic understanding of string theory, but I think I understand the role Calibi-Yau manifolds play in compactifying extra dimensions and hence influencing the behaviour of strings.
Suppose string theory is correct, in particular that the internal mechanisms of quantum particles and the way they influence gravitation incorporating higher-dimensional geometric shapes is true. Would these effects take place, so to speak, on "one side" of the universe, that is, on one plane of a hypersurface, or do they occur on a "second side" - a "flip side" - of the universe.
Someone once said, that for every "outside" there is an "inside". But if Einstein's field equations are true, and string theory has something to do with it, then even the Calibi-Yau shape that influences the behaviour of strings still could exist on the same "side" as the universe.
Perhaps it could be said, that such an "inside" of the universe is simply the premise of the afterlife, and that we may never know.
Is the universe "one-sided" or "double-sided"? What are your thoughts?

What is the "hypersurface"? And what does "on one plane of a hypersurface" means? 4D spacetime is not of codimension 1 in the manifold of string theory, like surfaces in 3D space, so it is not a hypersurface and it makes no sense to talk about its "sides". A better analogy is curves in 3D space, they are also not of codimension 1 and have no sides.

Could the people who upvoted this question please explain their reasoning?

With any theoretical model in physics, like QM & sigh string theory, we can make as many analogies as we want, but ultimately the guide is the math. Trying to reason from the partial analogies that are common in science communication will not give you useful predictions.

So you are saying that maybe advanced physics gives a basis for an afterlife? I don't see how that follows. If it can't be defended well, I don't think it is Philosophy either.

A question that requires graduate-level work in physics to even understand is not appropriate for a philosophy forum.

Suppose the Universe was just normal 3-d space- what would a 'side' be?

it is not true that for every outside there is an inside. A Moebius strip in 3 dimensions has only one side and one edge.

This is a very useful answer, and pretty much sets me on a good path

No.  the extra dimensions of superstring theory are just physical dimensions.  They have nothing to do with an afterlife.  The role Calibi-Yau manifolds play is that if those extra dimensions were not super complex geometrically, even if they were rolled up for a time, they would unroll spontaneously, and our universe would not be 3D.  The geometry of these other dimensions has to be very complex, like that of Calibri Yao manifolds, or else our 10 D universe would actually have 10 macro Ds. This is basically wild speculating by string theorists to find a patch to deal with a failed test case (the extra dimensions would not be stable except in a very few exotic geometries, defined by Calibri-Yao).
There is at the moment no evidence for any of these dimensions, nor that they could have such bizarre geometries.  IF they had such geometries, they would still not generate an afterlife.
